# How to get text from a non-matching sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ab-testing, vwo

I am creating an A/B test variant using VWO.
The website has a list with checkboxes laid out like so;

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox">
            <p class="checkBoxAnc">Text to grab</p>
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

There is an apply button, when this is clicked I want it to cycle through all of the inputs. If checked is true then I need to grab the text from the class "checkBoxAnc" (p element) and concatenate it to a variable.

I have tried the following:

```
var self= $(this);
//This is referring to the input that the user has clicked, so class '.checkBox'

self.next() // This doesn't work as element's do not match

self.nextUntil('.checkBoxAnc') // Same issue as .next()

var checkBoxSibling = self.parent().find('.checkBoxAnc').text();
// This returns an empty string
```

When trying to find the parent type this is being returned as 'undefined' rather than 'label'

Are there any other techniques to access '.checkBoxAnc'?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tu4tv5kq/). If you're having an issue, you need to provide a *complete yet minimal* demonstration that actually represents the issue.

Comment: Works here as expected using `next()` - https://jsfiddle.net/9vfyez40/ - try giving us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
var foo = '';

$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    foo += $(this).next().text(); // value your looking for
}).get();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmac_/8w7vghbt/

Comment: A `p` element has no value

Comment: I think you might want `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")`, I don't think your current selector will work.

Comment: @DBS It works, checkout the fiddle.  But yours is more widely used, so I'm gonna switch it.

Comment: Huh, indeed it does. I didn't realise you could stack up multiple `:` property selectors.